# Find Highest correlation values in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, correlation, pearson-correlation

I am looking to return the corr value between a dependent element and a series of independent variables.

Ideally this can be run in bigquery and is flexible by the number of variables tested increases or decreases.

Currently I'm using the Corr function in sheets, and holding the cells ($) so the dependent variable is always referenced

Sample Doc here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17TCfDBMg6OcfA9tUJgpmSGYQBmbG7OU_55Oc_h6nVfU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery also has [CORR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/statistical_aggregate_functions#corr) function:

```
CORR(X1, X2)  [OVER (...)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CORR` function to achieve the correlation between variables.

Here is an example based on your data:

```
select 
   corr(dependent_variable, v1) as v1_cor, 
   corr(dependent_variable, v2) as v2_corr, 
   corr(dependent_variable, v3) as v3_corr, 
   corr(dependent_variable, v4) as v4_corr 
from dataset.table
```